# Can i declare variable sheetname in formula "if" in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, navbar, solver

Can i declare variable sheetname in formula "if" in excel
This code get from vba macro.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF('1'!RC='2'!RC,'1'!RC,""R1:""&'1'!RC&""|R2:""&'2'!RC)"
```

(1 and 2 is sheetname)
I want to declare a variable, replacing 1 and 2.
such as:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF('i'!RC='i+i'!RC,'i'!RC,""R1:""&'i'!RC&""|R2:""&'i+i'!RC)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF('" & i & "'!RC='" & i + i & "'!RC,'" & i & "'!RC,""R1:""&'" & i & "'!RC &""|R2:""&'" & i + i & "'!RC)"
```

Comment: Use `i`  for the worksheet name.  At the top of the Sub-routine, put in `Dim i as string`.  You can then do things like `i = "Sheet1"`

Comment: Yeah, true, but the assumption here is that the sheet names are 1, 2, 3, etc. and that formula is being derived in a loop with "i" being used as the iteration variable.  Right or wrong, that's how I assumed it.  I don't know anyone that would use "i" as a string in VBA but sure, you could do that.

Comment: OP, beware of letting excel guess the variable type, so please use a `Dim` ... `as` ... statement. Also it makes it easier to troubleshoot errors and suggest ways to do stuff.

Comment: @mer_curius A formula does not care about the used variables. If it is followed by `!` Excel interprets it as a sheet name. If the sheet name contains spaces, it should be placed between `'` characters, if not, as in the OP case, they may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula (without modification) results in a circular reference. So, it's hard to give you a "correct" answer as such.
But in essence, using (e.g.) the context of the first sheet name, you'd
declare a string variable and set same to replace the reference to sheet '1'.

Assuming a viable result is to replace both sheet name and the `space handling` `'`, the simplest approach is something like:

```
Dim stShNm1$
stShNm1 = "'1'!"
```

Then change (e.g.):

```
"=IF('1'!RC
```

To:

```
"=IF(" &  stShNm1 & "RC
```

In this case of course, you's need variables (like) `stShNm1` and `stShNm2`.
But the principle remains the same, throughout your R1C1 formula construction.